# How to get id while in a loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

Wanted to get 2 values id and name but im confuse how get it, i wanted to show the id in the link. heres the sample code.

```
 echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\" bordercolor=\"#FFFFFF\">";

            $count = 1;
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            $col1 = $col2 = array();
            $rowcount = round(mysqli_num_rows($nquery) / 2);
            while($crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nquery)) { 
                if($count > $rowcount) $col2[] = $crow['title'];
                else $col1[] = $crow['title'];
                $count++;
            }
            $counter = 0; // Arrays start with 0
            foreach($col1 as $crow) { // $col1 will always be >= $col2
                $row2 = (isset($col2[$counter])) ? $col2[$counter] : "";
                echo "<tr><td><a href='index.php?page=".$id."'>" . $crow . "</td><td>" . $row2 . "</td></tr>"; 
                $counter++;
            }
            echo "</table>";
          ?>`
```

id wont show up on the link. Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I think that in 2018, people should no longer 1) inter-mix HTML with PHP, 2) extract direct $_GET values without escaping/validating them, and 3) execute DB statements in the middle of echos.

Comment: @Gabriel It's because for how much dangerously misinformed "tutorial" material there is out there for PHP and that severely compromises the new developer experience, especially for someone just getting started. The solution here is to use a development framework for web development, those can help tame the chaos that is a beginner's first app.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get $id values from the query string (that's what the $_GET superglobal is) and not from the database.

If both elements (ID and name) are coming from the same database query, you may try something like this:

```
$crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nquery);

foreach ($crow as $row)
{
    echo $row['id'].' is the ID and '.$row['title'].' is the title';
}
```

if you remain within the foreach loop, you can use $row['id'] and $row['title'] to build the table element and link you're trying to obtain.

Comment: so what happens to my col1 in my foreach statement? im trying to do 2 columns to display the title with links

Comment: Missed that... Could you post something that allows me to understand your database structure and the final result (not using variables, but related to fields in such structure)

it appears that you are trying to populate titles dinamically from fields in the query result, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out exactly what you are working with and what your expectation is

Comment: for example it will list data max 6 limit it will be in 2 columns 3 data in both columns but with link, in my code it will list only the title, but i cant figure how to put link on that title.